# What does the '' symbol mean in Python?

Tags: python

I've tried to complete a simple crypto challenge, called "readyXORnot". The text and the solution of this challenge are [here](https://github.com/shiltemann/CTF-writeups-public/tree/master/TAMUCTF-2017), just search "readyXORnot". Now I'm trying to understand the Python solution of the challenge and I'm stuck with this line of code. What does '' mean?

```
key = ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(orig,base64.b64decode(c)))
```

Comment: it's the empty string -- those are two single quotes.

Comment: Do you mean "what does ' mean"? there is not double quote in your code

Answer (score 0):

The '' you see is representative of an empty string (has no characters within it).

Answer (score 0):

In this challenge, you're probably creating the key

```py
key = ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(orig,base64.b64decode(c)))
```

This '' makes sure that all values generated after iterating over the for loop are combined without any spaces in between
eg.

```py
''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# Output: 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking what the `''` in `''.join()` means, it is an empty string defined by an opening ' and immediately followed by a closing ' (There is no " double quote). The code is generating a list with the `for a,b` bit, and then it is combining this list into a single string. This is done with the `.join()` method available to strings.

For example

```
myList = ['Hello', 'World']
print(''.join(myList))
```

> HelloWorld

As opposed to:

```
myList = ['Hello', 'World']
print(' '.join(myList)) # notice there is a space there now
```

> Hello World

You can even do silly things like:

```
myList = ['Hello', 'World']
print('b'.join(myList))
```

> HellobWorld